# Should I use these phrases in the same meaning?

Tags: usage

Should I use these phrases in the same meaning:

> the benefits of parents
>   the benefits of being parents

Comment: If you're a child, ***you*** get the *benefits of [having] parents*, but only the parents themselves can get *the benefits of **being** parents*.

Answer (score 1):

Your two sentences have slightly **different** meanings

> **the benefits of parents**

refers to the advantages of **having** parents

> the benefits of **being** parents
>   the benefits of **parenthood**

refers to the advantages of having kids, **parenthood**

Answer (score 0):

These two are different because the first one talks about the benefits that parents have whereas the second one talks about the benefits that people have on becoming parents.